# How to disable unbinded event

Tags: jquery

I'm using unbind to disable hover event and then want to enable it again.
How to do it?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   if(localStorage.getItem('options')=='disable'){
     $(".pasteOptions").unbind('hover',handler);
  }
 })
var handler = function() {
    alert('hi');
};
$(document).on('click','.copyOptions',function () {
   $('.pasteOptions').bind('hover',handler);
})
```

It doesn't work!

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What doesn't work?

Comment: i want to disable hover event on .pasteOptions and then enable it when click on .copyOptions

Comment: Your issue is that there isn't a `hover` event.  You can use `mouseenter mouseleave` to simulate this or you can use `.hover(func)`.

Comment: Also note that .bind/.unbind were deprecated in 2011 and removed in 2016.   So you might also like to include which ancient version of jquery you're using.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/category/events/mouse-events/

Comment: I have tried it by off() and on() to

Comment: Right, good link, **read it**.  You'll see, nowhere does it do `.on("hover")` it does `.hover` and `$( selector ).on( "mouseenter mouseleave", handlerInOut );`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there is not a DOM event `hover` - only `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

You can also use jquery `.hover` but can't use this with `.on`/`.off`.

Changing to `mouseenter mouseleave` gives you:

```js
// start with hover on so the .off does something
$('.pasteOptions').hover(handler);

$(document).ready(function () {
    // turn off the hover
    $(".pasteOptions").off('mouseenter mouseleave');
})
$(document).on('click','.copyOptions',function () {
   // turn on the hover 
   // (NB: turn it off first otherwise you get multiple events each time you click,
   //  this wouldn't normally how you do this, it would toggle on a tickbox or similar
   $(".pasteOptions").off('mouseenter mouseleave');
   $('.pasteOptions').hover(handler);
})

var handler = function() {
    // do something on hover
    $(this).toggleClass("hover");
};
```

```css
.pasteOptions, .copyOptions { height: 100px; width: 100px; border:1px solid blue; }
.hover { border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='copyOptions'>click me</div>
<div class='pasteOptions'>hover me</div>
```